# Conflicting Types Error within the same file?

Tags: c++, vxworks

I am building a VxWorks image, and it keeps getting hung up on one particular .cpp file. Here is the error:

```
C:\\Tornado2.2\\target\\src\\pmccommon\\pmcvxcommon.h:144: conflicting types for `typedef struct PMCDATA_STRUCT PMCDATA_STRUCT'
C:\\Tornado2.2\\target\\src\\pmccommon\\pmcvxcommon.h:144: previous declaration as `typedef struct PMCDATA_STRUCT PMCDATA_STRUCT'
C:\\Tornado2.2\\target\\src\\pmccommon\\pmcvxcommon.h:205: conflicting types for `typedef struct VX_DMA_MEMORY_MAP VX_DMA_MEMORY_MAP'
C:\\Tornado2.2\\target\\src\\pmccommon\\pmcvxcommon.h:205: previous declaration as `typedef struct VX_DMA_MEMORY_MAP VX_DMA_MEMORY_MAP'
C:\\Tornado2.2\\target\\src\\pmccommon\\pmcvxcommon.h:230: new declaration `struct PMCDATA_STRUCT * GetPmc(int)'
C:\\Tornado2.2\\target\\src\\pmccommon\\pmcvxcommon.h:230: ambiguates old declaration `struct PMCDATA_STRUCT * GetPmc(int)'
```

I've seen conflicting type errors before, but never when it's comparing to itself! What could this mean?

Here is line 127-144 of pmcvxcommon.h:

```
typedef struct
{
    >>lines 129-143
}PMCDATA_STRUCT;
```

PMCDATA_STRUCT is NOT declared elsewhere. This is the same for VX_DMA_MEMORY_MAP.

Any ideas?

Comment: Let me know what further information I can provide. I'll be gone over the weekend but on Monday morning I can answer any questions/comments if I did not provide enough info.

Comment: Still getting the same error even after putting #include guards in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try modifying the **pmcvxcommon.h** file as follows:

```
#ifndef PMCVXCOMMON_H
#define PMCVXCOMMON_H
... original content of file ...
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess: You're including that file multiple times within a given compilation unit.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be, though it may have gotten in twice through the header chain. I'll investigate. Thanks!

Comment: Just tested: The file I am currently building calls upon multiple header files, two of which require pmcvxcommon.h. The entire build fails without including it in both of these...

Comment: The typical solution is to #define __PMCVXCOMMON__H__ in pmcvxcommon.h, and then do an #ifdef to only #include it if that symbol is not yet defined.

Comment: Tried it over the weekend. It was a great idea to prevent multiple inclusion, but I'm still getting the exact same error even after putting #ifndef's everywhere that pmcvxcommon.h is called.